# Custom User Notice Upon Login

Tags: plugins, users, notifications

**Hello,**

I'm looking for either a plugin, or a way to display a custom notice for a specific user after they login. For example, let's say a user has a past due balance, I want to be able to go to the user's Wordpress profile, add a message/notice, and when the user logs in, the user see's the note attached to their account in the form of a lightbox.

Bonus: It would be even better if I could integrate with visual composer.

Comment: Are you familiar with WordPress development at all? Specifically PHP/HTML?

Comment: Hey @DaveLak Unfortunately, I'm not..

Answer (score 0):

You could add  code via the `wp_login()` hook; see how it works here:   https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_login .

The hook would be placed in your Child Theme's function.php file (always use a Child Theme; you never want to modify theme code, as your code changes will be overwritten on a theme update).